# Преобразование типов данных

Tags: javascript

```
var extra_fee_code=parseFloat(ans['extra_fee_code']);
```

После обработки, показывает значение NaN.
Как устранить ошибку?
function parse_answer(data){

```
try {window.notebook.hideProgress();}
catch(e) {}
if (data.indexOf('ERROR:') == 0) {
    document.getElementById("btn_next").disabled = false;
    try {window.notebook.alert(data.replace("ERROR:",""));}
    catch(e) {alert(data.replace("ERROR:",""));}
} else {
    var ans=parse_str(data);
    //ans['debt'] = 1929;

    var extra_fee_code=parseFloat(ans.extra_fee_code);
    var extra_fee_subcode=parseFloat(ans.extra_fee_subcode);
    var extra_fee_payable=parseFloat(ans.extra_fee_payable);
            var xfcounter_code=parseFloat(ans.xfcounter_code);
    var xfcounter_subcode=parseFloat(ans.xfcounter_subcode);
    var xfcounter_payable=parseFloat(ans.xfcounter_payable);
    var counter_code=parseFloat(ans.counter_code);
    var counter_subcode=parseFloat(ans.counter_subcode);
    var counter_tariff=parseFloat(ans.counter_tariff);
    var counter_previous_value=parseFloat(ans.counter_previous_value);
    var counter_decimal_percision=parseFloat(ans.counter_decimal_percision);
    var AccountInfo = ans.address+", кв. "+ans.flat + "<?=lang(' ЖЕО ',' ЖЕО ')?>" + ans.jek +  "<?=lang(' О/рахунок ',' О/рахунок ')?>" ;
            document.verify.jek.value = ans.jek;
    document.verify.account.value = ans.account;
    document.pay.period.value = ans.period;
    document.getElementById("account_info_ans").innerHTML = AccountInfo;
    document.getElementById("account_info_ans2").innerHTML = AccountInfo;
    document.pay.summ.value=ans.summ;
    document.pay.debt.value=ans.debt;
....................
Функция parse_str : парсит наши получаемые данные с БД и загоняет их в data.
В data мы получаем массив всех данных с базы функцией mysql_fatch_array($result);
```

Но как видимо в дата оно храниться не как массив, а как строка.
В итоге нам нужно распарсить в табличном виде все данные на страничке, использую функцию ParseFloat выводит у всех значений NaN кроме
extra_fee_list_details_html: undefined
extra_fee_list_html: undefined
xf_counter_list_html: undefined
counter_list_html: undefined
Как мы видим андефайн? Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Читайте документацию по функции parseFloat, в каких случаях она возвращает NaN и что это значит. И вообще, судя по Вашему "коду", Вы очень смутно себе представляете, что Вы делаете. Вы хотите, чтобы кто-то другой понял? И научитесь дебажить JavaScript - это очень важный навык, который помогает понять, что происходит в 90% случаев.

Answer (score 1):

У вас код начинается не с цифры,  поэтому parseFloat() не может преобразовать полученное значение в число и выдаёт NaN. Как устранить? Уберите parseFloat() и у вас будет сохраняться обычный string.

Comment: Перед тем как я поставил ParseFloat было eval, и тогда вообще никакой реакции не происходило, мне нужно распарсить данные, вот парсФлоат почти корректно работает, но не до конца все выводит. Вот вопрос, как заставить работать корректно?

Comment: Напишите больше подробностей, чему может быть равно ans['extra_fee_code'] и что вы хотите получить после парсинга

Comment: var ans=parse_str(data); - это делает переменная ans;
function parse_str(str, array){
    var glue1 = '=';
    var glue2 = '&';
    var array2 = str.split(glue2);
    var array3 = [];
    for(var x=0; x<array2.length; x++){
        var tmp = array2[x].split(glue1);
        array3[unescape(tmp[0])] = unescape(tmp[1]).replace(/[+]/g, ' ');
    }
    if(array){
        array = array3;
    } else{
        return array3;
    }
}
if ('undefined' == typeof String.prototype.crop) {
  String.prototype.crop = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
  }
} -это функция парса

Comment: И данные должны быть распарсены в табличном варианте, но оно не парсит их корректно. :(

Comment: Мои 2 вопроса в силе, и добавился ещё один:

1. Что вы получаете в data?  
2. Что вы хотите сделать с данными функцией parse_str и что получаете на выходе?
3. Что вы хотите сделать с данными после функции parse_str?

Все ответы добавьте в изначальный вопрос, и тогда, думаю, вам быстро помогут.